# DataGrid shows properties of DataGridView instead of data itself

Tags: c#, avaloniaui

I have a simple AvaloniaUI application following the MVVM pattern.

In my view, I have the following ContentControl

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding InputContent}" />
```

My ViewModel contains the following

```
private DataGrid inputContent = new();

public DataGrid InputContent
{
    get => this.inputContent;
    set
    {
        this.inputContent = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(InputContent));
    }
}

// this method is called during app runtime
private DoMagic()
{
    DataGrid dataGrid = new();
    DataTable dataTable = new("MyData");
    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int)));
    dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
    dataTable.Rows.Add(1, "Alice");
    dataTable.Rows.Add(2, "Bob");

    // This one behaves the same as AsDataView(); call
    // dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataTable.AsDataView();
    dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

    this.InputContent = dataGrid;
}
```

While debugging and using Visualizer on the `dataTable.DefaultView` call, I can see the data as expected.
[image: dataTable.DefaultView content]

But when the app executes the code and populates the `InputContent` with the `dataTable.DefaultView`, the `DataGrid` looks like this.

[image: DataGrid data]

After digging and debugging, I noticed that the `DataGrid` displays `DataRowView` instead of the data itself.

Any idea what this may be caused by? Or how to prevent the app from behaving like this?

Comment: What happens if you just assign the `DataTable` itself? When you bind a `DataTable` to standard WinForms controls, the data comes from the `DefaultView` anyway but it depends exactly how it's implemented as to whether that makes a difference in this case.

Comment: Data binding in WinForms is usually based on property descriptors rather than properties. That's how you can get data from a column in a `DataView` rather than actual properties of the `DataRowView` objects. If this particular control has not been implemented that way then it may not be possible to bind a `DataTable`/`DataView` and get what you want. You may need to define a type with appropriate properties and bid a list of that type instead.